# Show Apex message at another page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to display the message at another page when user click a button. 
Such as the user clicks button at Page A, then my action method will redirect user to Page B and show the message which is defined in the Page A controller.

Page A and Page B not use the same controller.

```
String pageHeaderReferer = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Referer'); 
if((pageHeaderReferer != null && pageHeaderReferer.containsIgnoreCase('Page1')) || isLtIE9()) 
{    
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, message)); 
}
```

Be careful, using the above code in IE8 that there is no 'Referer' value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way would be to pass the message as a parameter when redirecting the user, 
then have the second controller add that parameters content to the page.

**Controller 1**

```
public PageReference GoToPage2()
{
  ApexPages.PageReference pr = new ApexPages.PageReference(Page.Page2);
  pr.SetRedirect(true);
  pr.GetParameters().Put('message', 'Hello, World!');
  return pr;
}
```

**Page 1**

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!GoToPage2}" value="Page 2!"/>
```

**Controller 2**

```
public void Init()
{
  String message = '' + ApexPages.CurrentPage().GetParameters().Get('message');
  String pageHeaderReferer = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Referer'); 

  // Use the referrer parameter to only show the message when coming from Page 1
  if(pageHeaderReferer != null && pageHeaderReferer.containsIgnoreCase('Page1') && message != 'null')
  {
    ApexPages.CurrentPage().AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Info, message));
  }
}
```

**Page 2**

```
<apex:page controller="Page2Controller" action="{!Init}">
  <apex:pageMessages/>
```

The exact message syntax might be a little off, will double check it. It's one of those things I can remember when I'm coding but not when I'm just writing in the browser!

Comment: Thanks, but I think this will add a new parameter in the URL, if the user refresh the Page 2, the message will display again. I just want the message to display only one time.

Comment: You can always clear the parameter after reading it. An alternative mechanism would be writing it to a temporary object or custom setting (the latter might be better).

Comment: String pageHeaderReferer =    ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Referer');
        if(pageHeaderReferer != null && pageHeaderReferer.containsIgnoreCase('Page1'))
        {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,
                                    message));
        }

Comment: @LaceySnr Is it possible to make a conditional display? I have a situation where 'Submit' and 'Cancel' buttons on page 1 are going to redirect to the Page 2 but I want to display different messages according to the button's action. or do I have post a separate question for this?

Comment: @Seesh A new quesiton is best, you'll get rep that way!