# How to pass page message to arbitrary Page Reference

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, controller-extension

Is it possible to pass a page message to a newly created PageReference, so that this page will display it?

```
public PageReference doAction() {
   PageReference resultPage = new PageReference('/'+id);
   resultPage.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(...));

   return resultPage;
}
```

or

```
public PageReference doAction() {
   PageReference resultPage = Page.customPage;
   resultPage.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(...));

   return resultPage;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot add a message like this as it is stored in the page state, which gets lost when you redirect. Scenario 1 is out of the question as your `PageReference` points to a non-VF page. However, for scenario 2, why not just pass a URL parameter that the controller can read when the page loads, and create the appropriate message at that time.

Answer (score 2):

The following is only relevant to your second example, its not possible to share state between pages based on different controllers (as per ScottW's answer).

**Sharing State between Pages with the Same Controller.** I've just tried this, which I am sure I've seen work before and is [documented](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_System_PageReference_setRedirect.htm), but I'm getting a corrupted page back from Salesforce as result of the redirect. I've logged it as an answer just to illustrate what I've tried, as I thought it might have worked and still feel it should, perhaps a Salesforce bug?

```
<!-- messagepage1 -->
<apex:page controller="MessagePageController" action="{!doAction}">
</apex:page>

<!-- messagepage2 -->
<apex:page controller="MessagePageController">
    <apex:pageMessages />
</apex:page>

public with sharing class MessagePageController {
    public PageReference doAction()
    {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Info, 'Test message'));
        return Page.messagepage2;
    }
}
```

[image]

As per the docs...

> If set to false, the redirect is a server-side forward that preserves the view state if and only if the target page uses the same controller and contains the proper subset of extensions used by the source page.

So I also tried...

```
public PageReference doAction()
{
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Info, 'Test message'));
    PageReference page2 = Page.messagepage2;
    page2.setRedirect(false);
    return page2;
}
```

Without success either, very strange. So it may look like the answer is to pass the information as a parameter as per this question [Show Apex message at another page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13430/show-apex-message-at-another-page/13431#13431)

Comment: I've successfully passed messages through pages like this before, but as the documentation says, the controller and extensions must match, or it will be lost. In theory, the code in this answer should work. You may need to check the debug logs to see what's going on.

Comment: Yeah same here, really confused at this, nothing in the debug logs that jumps out, gets to constructing the page ref and exits.

Comment: Just checked my API versions and updated to 29, no dice! :-(

Comment: It doesn't work with redirects (page action) or reRender attributes, as far as I can tell. This page setup works:

Comment: `public with sharing class asktellmessagecontroller {
    public pagereference tellmessage() {
        apexpages.addmessage(new apexpages.message(apexpages.severity.confirm, 'Hello There!'));
        return page.tellmessage;
    }
}`

`<!-- ask message -->
<apex:page controller="asktellmessagecontroller">
    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:commandButton value="Tell Me!" action="{!tellmessage}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>`

`<!-- tellmessage -->
<apex:page controller="asktellmessagecontroller">
    <apex:pageMessages/>
</apex:page>`

Comment: Changing it to a page action, or adding a reRender attribute to the button causes it to fail.

Comment: Yeah sigh, i figured that might, nice to confirm this, now if only the question was "Why does action on the page not redirect and retain state?" ;-)

Comment: Actually, state is retained, but the messages are not. There's a distinct difference. I suspect this is a bug.