# Conditionally display a message at another page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I came across an easy way to [Show Apex message at another page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13430/show-apex-message-at-another-page/13431?noredirect=1#comment74034_13431) (code is given below). I have a situation where 'Save' and 'Cancel' buttons on page 1 are going to redirect to the Page 2 and display messages according to the button's action.' The best way to include a condition for displaying the message? Thanks.

Controller 1

```
public PageReference GoToPage2()
{
  ApexPages.PageReference pr = new ApexPages.PageReference(Page.Page2);
  pr.SetRedirect(true);
  pr.GetParameters().Put('message', 'Hello, World!');
  return pr;
}
```

Page 1

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!GoToPage2}" value="Page 2!"/>
```

Controller 2

```
public void Init()
{
  String message = '' + ApexPages.CurrentPage().GetParameters().Get('message');
  String pageHeaderReferer = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Referer'); 

  // Use the referrer parameter to only show the message when coming from Page 1
  if(pageHeaderReferer != null && pageHeaderReferer.containsIgnoreCase('Page1') && message != 'null')
  {
    ApexPages.CurrentPage().AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Info, message));
  }
}
```

Page 2

```
<apex:page controller="Page2Controller" action="{!Init}">
<apex:pageMessages/>
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what your question is... are you wanting to limit the message based on the originating page? Are you wanting it to say x if they click Save or y if they click Cancel? would both actions take them to page 2?

Comment: @BradBumbalough The buttons are in Page 1. Both the actions take them to page 2. Yes, If they click SAVE then display X in Page 2, if they click CANCEL display Y in Page 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way I would do it.... let me know if you are needing something different. Thanks!

**Page**:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!GoToPage2}">
   <apex:param name="action" assignTo="{!action}" value="Save"/>
</apex:commandButton>
<apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!GoToPage2}">
   <apex:param name="action" assignTo="{!action}" value="Cancel"/>
</apex:commandButton>
```

**Controller**:

```
public String action {get; set;}
public PageReference GoToPage2()
{
  ApexPages.PageReference pr = new ApexPages.PageReference(Page.Page2);
  pr.SetRedirect(true);
  pr.GetParameters().Put('message', 'Hello, World!');
  //pass a new param to the page of action
  pr.GetParameters().Put('action', action);
  return pr;
}
```

Comment: You are right.  I've followed and created in the same way and is working fine. Thank you @BradBumbalough.

Comment: Great! glad it worked.